# How authenticate and login functions work in django

Tags: django

In the code below, how does authenticate function validate the username and password. From where it pick the actual values to match against ?

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
```

Answer (score 2):

It takes a user name and password from the django User table. First you want to create a user entry in a django User table.

Refer following link to authenticate user and know more about Django authentication system.

[Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/)

Answer (score 1):

The `authenticate` function checks against your `User` model.

It takes the input from the form (`username` and `password`) to see if it aligns with a user in your database. If it does, it will log in that user. If it doesn't, an error message will occur.

Comment: for that I must create a user entry in User model? right. What is the correct way to make entry to User model. I see there is one entry and password is encrypted. How I create a new user in same way?

Comment: @User42 If you have admin access, you can create a new user in the Django admin page. If you do not have access, but have remote access via git or other, then you can use the function `python manage.py createsuperuser`. That will ask you for credentials to make a new user entry. Additionally, you can create a sign up screen to allow anyone to make an account from a general view in your project.

Comment: @User42 Not a problem. Good luck!